# Japanese contents are not visible in pdf file created using jasper soft version 6.13.0

Tags: pdf-generation

I have created a JRXML file using [Jasper Soft Studio](https://community.jaspersoft.com/project/jaspersoft-studio), version 6.13.0.
I can generate a PDF just fine with English content but it does not produce the expected output with Japanese text.

In the internal preview, Japanese texts are working fine but while using JRXML in Java andI generate a pdf, the Japanese text is displayed empty.

Kindly suggest me the solution

Comment: What do you mean with the internal preview?

Comment: Preview option present in the jaspersoft studio. After design i have checked the preview in jaspersoft studio with hard-coded japanese text which is working fine.